# Programmatically removing web parts in a sandbox solution? (Sharepoint 2010)

Tags: development, web-part, sandbox-solution

I had a problem with web parts being duplicated whenever their feature was reactivated, so [I made a question about that](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/66479/forms-being-re-appended-to-themselves-on-every-deployment-sharepoint-2010).

It was answered (and correctly so, I think) - I have to programmatically remove the duplicates. However, in sandbox solutions you just can't use the **SPLimitedWebPartManager** class, which is needed for all the straightforward removal techniques.

So how can I remove web part in a sandbox solution, via code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is short - you cannot do that using a Sandboxed solution.

Comment: Sad but true. Unfortunately, deploying our solution as a sandbox one is one of our requirements.